# Hawking Radiation: Field decomposition

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In his [1975 paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02345020), Hawking solves the Klein–Gordon equation in Schwarzschild spacetime and gets incoming and outgoing solutions
$$
f_{\omega^{\prime} l m}=(2 \pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}} r^{-1}\left(\omega^{\prime}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} F_{\omega^{\prime}}(r) e^{i \omega^{\prime} v} Y_{l m}(\theta, \phi),$$
and
$$p_{\omega l m}=(2 \pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}} r^{-1} \omega^{-\frac{1}{2}} P_{\omega}(r) e^{i \omega u} Y_{l m}(\theta, \phi).$$

Then, we can decompose the field operator $\phi$ on the entire spacetime as a superposition of spherical waves,
$$\phi=\sum_{l, m} \int \mathrm{d} \omega\left(a_{\omega l m} f_{\omega l m}+a_{\omega l m}^{\dagger} f_{\omega l m}^{ *}\right).$$

My questions are: Does this decomposition hold for the entire spacetime (or for all values of Schwarzschild time)? Incoming and outgoing solutions should satisfy completeness relation — do they satisfy only at asymptotic infinity ($r \to \infty$) or everywhere (I believe that exact form of $F_{\omega^{\prime}}(r)$ is not known)? What is the physical meaning of restricting solutions to these of positive frequency?